# How to combine 2 arrays and label them into a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
var a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58];
var b = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"];
```

I'm trying to combine 2 arrays so they matchup to each value, and also giving them a label of y and period.

```
[{y:100, period:2012},{y:100, period:2013},{y:100, period:2015}, ...]
```

I have been trying to do it the following way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

items = items.concat($.map(a[i].items,function(elem){
        return {y:elem.a, period:elem.b};
    }));
}
console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do with `Array#map` .no need a `forloop` .you are using wrong returning call .Do with `({key:value})`

```js
var a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58];
var b = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"];

var items = a.map(function(i,k){
    return ({y:i,period:b[k]})
})
console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newarr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    newarr[i]={'y': a[i], 'period': b[i]};
}
```

That's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use map function like below.

```
var a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58];
    var b = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"];

    var fullArr = [];
    var i = 0;

    fullArr = $.map(a, function(curVal, index, arr){
      return [{y:curVal, period:b[index]}];
    });

    console.log(fullArr);
```

Please check below jsfiddle

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kitcodes/w7o7oqdv/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map`

```js
const a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58],
      b = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"];

var result = a.map((n,i) => ({y : n , period:b[i]}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```js
const a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58],
      b = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"];

var result = a.map(function (n,i){
  return ({y : n , period:b[i]})
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You're using arrow functions. IE11 doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58];
var b = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"];

var items = [];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  var item = {
    y: a[i],
    period: b[i]
  };
  items.push(item);
}
console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array for the keys and iterate the values.

```js
var a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58],
    b = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
    cols = ['y', 'period'],
    result = [a, b].reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j) {
            r[j] = r[j] || {};
            r[j][cols[i]] = b;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58],
    b = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
    cols = ['y', 'period'],
    result = [a, b].reduce((r, a, i) =>
        Object.assign(r, ...a.map((b, j) => ({ [j]: Object.assign(r[j] || {}, { [cols[i]]: b }) })))
    , []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two way . examples are given below.

**1) jQuery.merge()**

> Merge the contents of two arrays together into the first array.

**example**

```
var first = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
var second = [ "d", "e", "f" ];
$.merge( $.merge( [], first ), second );
```

**Result**

```
[ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" ]
```

**2) jQuery.extend()**

> Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

**example**

```
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: { price: 200 },
  durian: 100
};

// Merge object2 into object1
$.extend( object1, object2 );

// Assuming JSON.stringify - not available in IE<8
$( "#log" ).append( JSON.stringify( object1 ) );
```

**Result**

```
{"apple":0,"banana":{"price":200},"cherry":97,"durian":100}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in simple way.

```js
var a = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58];
var b = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"];
var items = {};
var final = [];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
 items = {};
 items.y = a[i]  
 items.period = b[i]
 final.push(items);
};
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use **forin** array of JavaScript

```js
var arr1 = [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 21.88, 28.13, 21.88, 25.81, 22.58],
    arr2 = ["2012", "2013", "2015", "2012", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
    finalArr = [],key;

for (key in arr1) {
    finalArr.push({
        y: arr1[key],
        period: arr2[key]
    })
}

console.log(finalArr);
```